# Named instances of SQL Server that I did not installed

Tags: sql, sql-server, instance

I just installed SQL Server 2014 enterprise with default instance (hit next next). But what I happened to find that I had 4 different instances of SQL Server. One of them is 2016 version also.

The list of instances are

```
localdb\MSSQLLocalDB
localdb\ProjectsV12
```

This one is version 2016 and express edition

```
localdb\ProjectsV13
MyComputerName(default instance)
```

I did not installed named instances how they got to my computer. Is it Visual Studio that installed the other instances for its own use? By the way I saw these list from Visual Studios SQL Server Object Explorer window when I tried to add a new server. Under the.local servers pan these instances were listed

Comment: are you using visual studio. then it will install while creating a database server project in it.

Comment: These are pre-defined SQL Server Express **LocalDB** instances - intended for use during development

Comment: @marc_s After the development do we have to migrate databases to different server or can we still use localdb while in use? Also I saw one of my codefirst practice database that I did not specify a connection string, in localdb server. So Can we say, VS will always use this server if you do not explictly specify a server –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually they are installed via Visual Studio:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233763.aspx

Comment: So when you create database from visual studio,by default it creates that database in this localdb server.